# Show that $X$ is not definable in $(\Bbb{R}, <)$

Tags: model-theory

The question is as follows:

> Let $X = \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 : z = x + y\}$. Show that $X$ is not definable in $(\Bbb R, <)$.

I tried to show that $(\Bbb R, <)$ has only two subsets that are definable, namely $\Bbb R$ and the empty set using an automorphism argument. Since $X$ is neither of these sets it is not definable in $(\Bbb R, <)$. I feel like this approach is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does "definable" mean definable with or without parameters?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I believe with parameters. I'm using the first definition given here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set

Comment: Regarding your attempt: you're right that there are only two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are definable *without* parameters. But $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not $\mathbb{R}$, and you want to show $X$ is not definable even *with* parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that for any finite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and any element $b\notin A$, there is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ which fixes the elements of $A$ but moves $b$.

Now obtain a contradiction to the above fact under the assumption that $X$ is definable.

Comment: Could you tell me if I'm on the right track? For any finite subset A of R there is a ∈ A and b ∈ R / A. Consider the map  f: R -> R given by f(r) = r + (b - a). F is easily check able an automorphism. F(A) =/= A since f(a) = b.

Comment: @FordWendy Even easier than your argument : a definable set is stable under automorphisms . Consider the finite set $A = \{1,2\}$ and let $b = 3$, there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ fixing $A$ pointwise but such that $\sigma(3) \neq 3$. Now, $(1,2,3) \in X$ but $\sigma((1,2,3)) = (1,2,\sigma(3)) \notin X$. Hence, $X$ isn't definable.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Right - and to rule out definability with parameters, you should also let $A$ contain the definitely many parameters used in the definition (and pick something other than $b=3$ if $3$ happened to be a parameter).